# Can't export flash video

Tags: flash, flash-cs4

I'm about to lose my mind.  I have Flash CS3 and I want to export my animation as a movie.  However my animation is in a clip and my clip is on the timeline.  For some reason it only exports the first frame of the clip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Export as movie" only works with animations on the main timeline.  Any animation nested within movie clips will not render/execute.  That's just the way it works.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your main timeline is long enough for the entire movieclip to play.  If your main timeline is shorter than your MovieClip object timeline then the export may be cutting off at the length of the main timeline.  If your movieclip object is sitting on a single frame main timeline this might be the explanation.

Comment: Yes that's what happening but when I tried making the main timeline long enough, it still only shows the first frame of my movieclip, except it stretches it out for the entire length that I make the timeline.